# Is it possible to display an Android webview as a Native Extension in AIR?

Tags: android, air

Is it possible to display a webview on the stage via a native extension in an AIR app published for Android?

Answer (score 1):

No, but the ANE can launch a new Activity which contains a webview. (but not embbed a webview inside a stage)

The best is to use directly the Adobe Air widget StageWebView.

Comment: I believe the widget mentioned would be StageWebView.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use adobe's StageWebview or myappsnippet's RichWebview https://github.com/myflashlab/webView-ANE (I'm the developer of RichWebview, feel free to ask questions if you might have any)